# Excel Conditional Formatting for cells that re equal to 0 formats also blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have columns filled with this possible data

- 0
- 1
- na
- blank cells

I want to apply conditional formatting with this rules:

- if cell value = 0 , then the background is red
- if cell value = 1 , then the background is green

[image]

Unfortunately if I create the rules for value =0, it is also colouring the 'blank' cells red:

[image]

My rules look like this:

[image]

I have also put special rule just to switch all banks to white but it has no effect.
I have tried to change the rule for the "0" in many ways like checking if the value is between 0 and 0, but still the rule always colours the blanks. How can I create rule which will leave the blanks white and colour only the "0" cells?

I went through couple examples from Stackoverflow which suppose to fix this issue, but I dont know how to apply formulas in generic way for whole columns - I am not working with Excel on daily basis so I dont know how to create advanced formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula for the red part:

`=(D1=0)*(D1<>"")`

It returns true if the cell isn't empty and the value = 0.

(Btw: like this the condition is international ... you could use `AND` or  `ISNUMERIC` as well - but then in the language of your Excel: `=AND(ISNUMBER(D1),D1=0)`)

Comment: This works, i will accept the answer, just one question why the formula referes to the D1 cell?

Comment: Because your "Applies to"-range in the screenshot starts with D1.

Comment: I see, this was the part which I was always missing when trying different formulas, because they referred to some cells and I did not know why. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Move to the first position the Blank test criteria:

[image]